# How to make a new project in YII without testdrive

Tags: php, yii

I want to create a project from scratch..say **without** that command .

```
./framework/yiic web`app
```

How can i do that.
I made a directory naming myproject and added a controller and config main file and index.php having same as testdrive project. But i am still getting this error :

```
CHttpException
Unable to resolve the request “site/error”. (/var/www/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php:286)
```

What can be the case here??

Comment: Please also provide the following information: local URL and directory structure, urlManager format value, contents of .htaccess file.

Comment: Generate app, delete what unnessesary, add your favorite extensions and save for later use.

Comment: Yeah, what PeterM said.

Comment: does your SiteController have a public actionError?

Answer (score 0):

Look into your config.php file and make sure that this piece of code:

```
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
```

is correctly configured. The setting above looks for a method `actionError()` in your SiteController. If the name of your controller isn't SiteController, make the appropriate changes and you should be fine.